# What's a word or phrase for lacking the normal fear of a particular danger?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The logical opposite of having an irrational fear (or phobia) is *not* having that fear. But what is the opposite condition, the condition of having an irrational *lack* of fear for something that *should* frighten, such as, let's say, being burned? It's not *philia* since there's no particular affinity for it either, and it's not *courage* as stated in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47512/antonym-of-phobia) since courage is something mustered for a particular situation.

Comment: Why do you assume fear is natural, that dangers "should frighten"? Can't one simply be rational and prudent, knowing that it's not wise to stick one's hand in the fire?

Comment: The psychological term for way out-of-whack risk assessment is **disinhibition**.

Comment: Probably some combo using *a...phobic* would be close.

Comment: Huh.. I should have read the body. Anyway the logical opposite can have many dimensions and one can negate any one of the many attributes. So yours is an irrational _lack_ of having a fear. Like you _should_ be afraid of unconstrained heights.

Comment: I agree with *foolhardy,* below, which means the person would be taking a foolish risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that comes closest was *[**disinhibition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disinhibition)*, which was in Tim Romano's comment.

> In psychology, *disinhibition* is a lack of restraint manifested in disregard for social conventions, impulsivity, and poor risk assessment. Disinhibition affects motor, instinctual, emotional, cognitive, and perceptual aspects with signs and symptoms similar to the diagnostic criteria for mania.
>   <sub>*Wikipedia*</sub>

*Foolhardy* implies general disregard for any danger, while *disinhibition* suggests lack of inhibition for some particular thing, since "inhibition" connotes, like "phobia," aversion to something specific.

Answer (score 6):

Before every human quirk had an official psych diagnosis, the behavior of a person who did not feel fear when it would be prudent (and thus seemed overly bold, irresponsible, or even, suicidal,) was called ***"foolhardy".***

See: http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/foolhardy

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Tonepoet.  (Not sure I got the resource right, but I gave it a shot.)

Comment: Thank you for paying heed to my advice.  I still think a direct quote with attribution to the printed source, along the lines of  "Definition" — A.D.E.L. ([year/edition]), with an embedded link in the word would be best due to [linkrot](http://journalistsresource.org/studies/society/internet/website-linking-best-practices-media-online-publishers) but perhaps it's not as necessary due to the inherently attributive qualities of that site's U.R.L. and abundent distribution nature of the content. You might still want to put See: before the U.R.L. to make it clear that you're not quoting it though.

Comment: This answer would have been better in response to the past edit version of the question that removed the sense of *particular* dangers which my original question included. It is less relevant, in my view, now that this sense has been restored.

Answer (score 1):

> *reckless* — having or showing no regard for danger or consequences; heedless; rash

American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved August 20 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reckless

Answer (score 0):

The word *folly* comes to mind.

> the lack of good sense or judgment
>
> a foolish act or idea : foolish behavior

(Meriam-Webster on-line)

Another word that comes to my mind is *bravado*.

> A swaggering show of defiance or courage.
>
> A false show of courage.

(Wiktionary)

Comment: (Like my answer) this does not speak specifically to lack of concern about *danger*.

Answer (score 0):

*insouciant*: Marked by blithe unconcern. ([WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=insouciant))

But this is more general than unconcern about *danger*.